# WxPython adding text in a specific place

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxtextctrl, textctrl

In the GUI that I make (With wxpython), I need to append text in a specific place of the TextCtrl (I can change it to other textEntry if it is needed). 
for example I have this text:
Yuval is a surfer.
He likes (*HERE*) to go to the beach.

I want to append a word or couple of words after the word "likes". How can I do that using wxpython modoule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always know the word after which you want to add other words you could do something like this:

```
new_text = 'Yuval is a surfer'
search_text = 'likes'
original_text = "He likes to go to the beach."
result = original_text.replace(search_text, " ".join([search_text, new_text]))

print(result)

#Prints: "He likes Yuval is a surfer to go to the beach."
```

If, on the contrary, what you know is the position of the word after which other words must be added:

```
new_text = 'Yuval is a surfer'
word_pos = 1
original_text = "He likes to go to the beach."

#convert into array:
splitted = original_text.split()
#get the word in the position and add new text:
splitted[word_pos] = " ".join([splitted[word_pos], new_text])
#join the array into a string:
result = " ".join(splitted)
print(result)

#Prints: "He likes Yuval is a surfer to go to the beach."
```

Hope this helps.